# ProcessBuilder in Android

Tags: java, android

I wrote a simple application that needs to run external programs as superuser. I run this piece of code in a periodic task: the code is contained in a Runnable that runs periodically by using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. The code works well for a while, but after some times it stops to work. To do that I used the following code. By debugging the application I found the problem is in the line **Process process = builder.start();**

I mean that when the problem happens the execution wait the return of this method forever.

```
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("su");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = builder.start();
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                    process.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader bRes = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream()));
            os.writeBytes("busybox ifconfig | busybox grep 'eth'; echo done_done\n"); //<-- this is my command for now
            os.flush();
            String r;
            long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();             
            while ((r = bRes.readLine()).equals("done_done") == false){
                results.add(r);
            }
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
```

Any suggestions? I can't figure out what kind of problems produce this situation. I used this code in past without problems.

Thank you,
Nico